# How authenticate a php website with google spreadsheet

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-sheets, google-authentication

I want to use Google Spreadsheets as a database when somebody fills out a form. Currently I have been able to use google spreadsheets with google account that does not have the two step authentication enabled. I did that with the Zend Framework.

I want to take it one step further and use the two step authentication so that even authenticated google account will also be able to store information in Google Spreadsheets.

I have a php website, how can I ask the user to authenticate and enable his website to access his spreadsheets and write in them.

I am seriously stuck. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Comment: I don't have a clue as to where should I approach the authentication of a website to a google email account. Have you accomplished something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you will need to use [OAuth2 with Google Speadsheets API v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20). This will allow users of your app to give it access to their Google docs.